# How to determine what version of the GCC compiler is used at www.ideone.com when C++ 11 is selected?

Tags: c++, gcc

How to determine what version of the `GCC` compiler is used at www.ideone.com when `C++ 11` is selected? I am interested how to quickly see the version of GCC that is used in the IDE of www.ideone.com, because sometimes the version of the compiler was not specified.

I am not interested to determine the version using a code. I need to quickly determine what is the current version of the compiler without running a program.

Comment: Hover over C++11 in the right "sidebar".

Comment: @Mat Early there was an explicit remark about the used version of the compiler. Now it is deleted by unknown reason. In any case write your answer and I will mark it as the best.

Comment: Use [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox)

Answer (score 3):

Use `__VERSION__`.

[**This code**](http://ideone.com/Bck2wb) gives me 4.8.1 as the output.

Comment: You should have linked to coliru just for laughs ;)

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to `__VERSION__` which has unspecified format (afaik) you can use `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` to identify the version of GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << __GNUC__ << "." << __GNUC_MINOR__ << "." << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__;
  return 0;
}
```